# Gradle with cpp-application plugin, how to set up an include path?

Tags: gradle, dependencies, include

This is a newbie question, sorry if it is obvious. I have a c++ Vulkan test program that includes a vulkan.h file.

That file (and other files it includes, such as vulkan-core.h) is located in a central location provided by our IT people, for example, C:\include\vk.

I want to tell build.gradle to fetch vulkan.h from that directory (I'm using the cpp-application plugin), but so far no success. I need something similar to the visual studio include path, but if possible I'd rather avoid being dependent on any specific compiler or toolchain.

Alberto.

Answer (score 1):

I did something like that by adding this to the build.gradle :

```
application {
    privateHeaders {
        from("/path/to/your/include/dir/")
    }
}
```